# Should the resque-scheduler queue be expected to handle /lots/ of delayed jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I am currently using resque and resque-scheduler in an application that will have to handle a lot of recurring jobs - "do this every hour", "do this every day" etc. At the moment, I simply queue up the next run of the job in the job itself, the HourlyJob queue has a .enqueue_at(1.hour.from_now, HourlyJob) etc.

Should I be doing this? It "feels" like I should have a static recurring job using resque-schedulers cron-type functionality that then schedules up say the next 5 minutes worth of delayed jobs... but all I am really doing is moving the work from the (probably fast, redis based) resque-scheduler to my (probably less well implemented, mysql based) code, surely?

Is there anything wrong with how I'm doing it now?

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use the cron style provided by resque-scheduler, your use case is exactly what it was built for:

- Your more directly indicate these are recurring jobs.
- Everything is located in the same YAML file rather then multiple job classes/modules.

By queuing the next run of the job inside the actual job:

- You run the risk of the next run going missing when your worker/job/server fails.
- Your needlessly using more memory in Redis, the scheduler process will not add the jobs to Redis until there ready to be run.

Hops this helps.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. :)
The problem is that these jobs are not static, and the cron style scheduler seems to be only for static jobs - there will be many dynamic, recurring jobs, and this is whats throwing me. Is there a way to "rehash" the cronlike job file without restarting the schduler every time a new job is scheduled?